# R purrr pmap Can't pluck from a closure

Tags: r, purrr

What am I doing wrong here?:

```
library(tidyverse)
calling_dataset <- tibble(filepath="xxx.csv")

testfunction1 <- 
 getdrugdata <- function(filepath){
   print(filepath)
 }

test1 <- calling_dataset %>%  
  purrr::pmap_df(list(
  .$filepath), testfunction1)
```

The resulting error is:  Error: Can't pluck from a closure.

Answer (score 0):

change the invocation:

```
purrr::pmap_df(list(calling_dataset$filepath), testfunction1)
```

Order is restored to the universe.